# How i can receive the name of an image searched in html file object

Tags: php, html

Image of File Object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSNoD.jpg

HTML of File Object:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

I want to receive the name of the image that i search in file object. In that image i want to receive Practidose.fw.png

I try to do this:

```
$imagem = mysql_escape_string($_POST['file']);
```

And i receive this error:

Undefined index on line 113

And i dont receive the name of the image

Comment: All the information about uploaded files is in `$_FILE`, not `$_POST`. Read the documentation on uplading files with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$_FILE` to get your file instead of `$_POST.` Check [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for more information.

```
$filename = $_FILE['file']['name']; 
// name of the image is now in the variable $filename
```

Answer (score 0):

use the correct file array of php.

Use this

$imagem = mysql_escape_string($_POST['file']['name'); instead of

$imagem = mysql_escape_string($_POST['file']);